# tmux status-bar #(pwd) doesn't reload

Tags: tmux

I have a problem with the tmux 2.1 status bar. As the manual explains I'd write in ~/.tmux.conf it:

```
set -g status-right "#(/bin/pwd) %R %d/%m/%g"
set -g status-interval 1
```

After I start tmux in status bar is /home/conformist. But if I change cwd (like cd /) — status bar is still $HOME.

Everything works perfect if I change conf to:

```
set -g status-right "#{pane_current_path} %R %d/%m/%g"
```

I'd like to look in status bar $HOME like ~ and cannot do this, because pwd doesn't change (and pwd | perl -pne s-$HOME-~- doesn't work too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `/bin/pwd` like that will not work because the program is run by the same process (it is **not** your shell).  If you are using `bash`, you can modify your prompt to send an escape sequence to `tmux` to change the window name using the escape sequence shown as an example:

```
printf '\033kWINDOW_NAME\033\\'
```

Here is a separate shell script to demonstrate the escape sequence:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf '\033k%s\033\\' $(pwd)
```

It is not the same escape sequence used for xterm titles, but you can apply the advice in the [Bash Prompt HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/xterm-title-bar-manipulations.html) in the same way.

Further reading:

- [Bash Prompt HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/)

Answer (score 3):

## Working ENV:

### OS

- OSX 10.14.5

### Terminal

- Alacritty 0.3.3 - https://github.com/jwilm/alacritty
- iTerm2 3.2.9 - https://iterm2.com/
- Apple Terminal 2.9.5

### Tmux

- tmux 2.9a

## Example status-right field

`~/.tmux.config` to call out to an external bash script in the example provided, the file is here: `~/.tmux_path.sh`

### ~/.tmux.config

```bsh
set -g status-interval 1
set -g status-right-length 150
set -g status-right "#(~/.tmux_path.sh #{pane_current_path}) %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Example bash script that reads #{pane_current_path) arg.  `basename` truncates the beginning path and just displays current.  This is nice if using as a window id.
NOTE: This is making an assumption that `$HOME = /home/user` one might need to adjust `-f-1,4-` to match the desired outcome.

### ~/.tmux_path.sh

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
printf '\033%s\007' $(echo "$1" | awk '{print "~"$1}' | cut -d/ -f-1,4-)
```

### Make script executable

```bsh
chmod +x ~/.tmux_path.sh
```

## Example window naming

- Note: Use the same `~/.tmux_path.sh` from above

### ~/.tmux.conf

```bsh
set -g status-interval 1
set -g window-status-current-format "[#[fg=white] #(~/.tmux_path.sh #{pane_current_path})]"
set -g window-status-format "#[fg=black] #(~/.tmux_path.sh #{pane_current_path})"
```